# tcServer JVM crash - EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: grails, jenkins, jvm, java-6, tcserver

We are attempting to deploy a Grails(v2.1.0) application onto our tcServer(v2.0.2), which we have done without issue in lower environments and are unable to start it up.

Stacktrace:

```
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006da0309a, pid=5944, tid=4276
    #
    # JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # V  [jvm.dll+0x12309a]
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x0000000005409800):  JavaThread "WrapperSimpleAppMain" [_thread_in_vm, id=4276, stack(0x00000000069b0000,0x00000000069e0000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x000000036d7c8e70

    Registers:
    RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000005409800, RCX=0x0000000000000003, RDX=0x000000036d7c8e00
    RSP=0x00000000069dab40, RBP=0x00000000069dac90, RSI=0x00000000054099d0, RDI=0x0000000005409800
    R8 =0x000000000000002f, R9 =0x0000000074bd1607, R10=0x000000000000002f, R11=0x00000007e88646a8
    R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000069daea8, R14=0x00000000069daed8, R15=0x00000000069daee0
    RIP=0x000000006da0309a, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000069dab40)
    0x00000000069dab40:   0000000005409800 00000000069dac90
    0x00000000069dab50:   0000000074bd15d8 00000000054099d0
    0x00000000069dab60:   0000000005409800 0000000000000000
    0x00000000069dab70:   00000000053e9950 0000000b0000005f
    0x00000000069dab80:   000000000000004a 0000000074bd3634
    0x00000000069dab90:   00000000054099d0 00000000069dac90
    0x00000000069daba0:   000000000541f010 0000000005409800
    0x00000000069dabb0:   000000006de96cc8 0000000000000000
    0x00000000069dabc0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x00000000069dabd0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x00000000069dabe0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x00000000069dabf0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x00000000069dac00:   0000000000000000 00000000011707e0
    0x00000000069dac10:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x00000000069dac20:   0000000000000000 00000000069daea8
    0x00000000069dac30:   00000000069daec0 0000000000000000 

    Instructions: (pc=0x000000006da0309a)
    0x000000006da0307a:   00 48 8b 17 74 16 8b 52 08 0f b6 0d b6 61 5e 00
    0x000000006da0308a:   48 d3 e2 48 03 15 a4 61 5e 00 eb 04 48 8b 52 08
    0x000000006da0309a:   48 8b 52 70 48 8b ce e8 4a 98 0c 00 48 83 7c 24
    0x000000006da030aa:   28 00 48 8b f0 74 0a 48 8d 4c 24 20 e8 55 72 12 


    Register to memory mapping:

    RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    RBX=0x0000000005409800 is a thread
    RCX=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
    RDX=0x000000036d7c8e00 is an unknown value
    RSP=0x00000000069dab40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000005409800
    RBP=0x00000000069dac90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000005409800
    RSI=0x00000000054099d0 is an unknown value
    RDI=0x0000000005409800 is a thread
    R8 =0x000000000000002f is an unknown value
    R9 =0x0000000074bd1607 is an unknown value
    R10=0x000000000000002f is an unknown value
    R11=0x00000007e88646a8 is an unknown value
    R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    R13=0x00000000069daea8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000005409800
    R14=0x00000000069daed8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000005409800
    R15=0x00000000069daee0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000005409800


    Stack: [0x00000000069b0000,0x00000000069e0000],  sp=0x00000000069dab40,  free space=170k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    V  [jvm.dll+0x12309a]

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext([B[I[BI[B[I[ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)I+0
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.GenerateClientContext([BI[B[I[Z)I+24
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.SSPIData([B[B[I[ZLcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/AuthenticationJNI;)V+13
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand;Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/AuthenticationJNI;)V+155
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand;)V+20
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection;Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand;)V+2
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute()Z+5
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/TDSWriter;Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/TDSReader;)Z+30
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/TDSCommand;)Z+45
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/ServerPortPlaceHolder;II)V+284
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/FailoverInfo;IJ)V+399
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Ljava/util/Properties;Lcom/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerPooledConnection;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+1929
    j  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+45
    j  org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection()Ljava/sql/Connection;+12
    j  org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
    j  org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(Lorg/apache/commons/dbcp/PoolableConnectionFactory;)V+3
    j  org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(Lorg/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory;Lorg/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory;Lorg/apache/commons/dbcp/AbandonedConfig;)V+49
    j  org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource()Ljavax/sql/DataSource;+71
    j  org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection()Ljava/sql/Connection;+1
    j  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(Ljavax/sql/DataSource;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+79
    j  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+281
    j  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.getMetaData()Ljava/sql/DatabaseMetaData;+9
    j  org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(Ljavax/sql/DataSource;Lorg/springframework/jdbc/support/DatabaseMetaDataCallback;)Ljava/lang/Object;+43
    j  org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(Ljavax/sql/DataSource;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+9
    j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernateDialectDetectorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()V+26
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;)V+107
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;)Ljava/lang/Object;+61
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+230
    j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+11
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+122
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject()Ljava/lang/Object;+16
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory;)Ljava/lang/Object;+126
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+307
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/RuntimeBeanReference;)Ljava/lang/Object;+94
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+15
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map;+79
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+300
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition;Lorg/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper;Lorg/springframework/beans/PropertyValues;)V+231
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition;Lorg/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper;)V+339
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+217
    j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+11
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+122
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+351
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/RuntimeBeanReference;)Ljava/lang/Object;+94
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+15
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition;Lorg/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper;Lorg/springframework/beans/PropertyValues;)V+231
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition;Lorg/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper;)V+339
    j  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+217
    j  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/RootBeanDefinition;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+11

    ...spring framework...

    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(Lorg/apache/catalina/Container;)V+26
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(Lorg/apache/catalina/Container;)V+50
    j  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/String;)V+617
    j  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(Ljava/io/File;[Ljava/lang/String;)V+223
    j  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps()V+25
    j  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start()V+229
    j  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(Lorg/apache/catalina/LifecycleEvent;)V+132
    j  org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+37
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start()V+306
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start()V+315
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start()V+266
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start()V+221
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start()V+133
    j  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start()V+88
    j  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start()V+50
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
    j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
    j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
    j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
    j  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start()V+37
    j  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+131
    j  net.covalent.tomcat.wrapper.ThreadDumpWrapper.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+248
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
    j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
    j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
    j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
    j  org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run()V+55
    j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x000000000710b000 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4992, stack(0x00000000067f0000,0x0000000006820000)]
      0x0000000007109000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5216, stack(0x0000000007670000,0x00000000076a0000)]
      0x0000000007108000 JavaThread "RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:6969]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4860, stack(0x00000000075b0000,0x00000000075e0000)]
      0x00000000070dc000 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9024, stack(0x0000000007580000,0x00000000075b0000)]
      0x00000000070db800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3940, stack(0x0000000007550000,0x0000000007580000)]
      0x0000000007445800 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=10896, stack(0x0000000006c80000,0x0000000006cb0000)]
      0x0000000006f36000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-6969" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2576, stack(0x0000000006c50000,0x0000000006c80000)]
      0x0000000007240000 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8700, stack(0x0000000006a10000,0x0000000006a40000)]
    =>0x0000000005409800 JavaThread "WrapperSimpleAppMain" [_thread_in_vm, id=4276, stack(0x00000000069b0000,0x00000000069e0000)]
      0x00000000005ad000 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=5804, stack(0x0000000000230000,0x0000000000260000)]
      0x000000000553f800 JavaThread "Wrapper-Connection" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10720, stack(0x0000000006950000,0x0000000006980000)]
      0x0000000005496000 JavaThread "Wrapper-Control-Event-Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9340, stack(0x00000000067c0000,0x00000000067f0000)]
      0x00000000053f7000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3268, stack(0x0000000005310000,0x0000000005340000)]
      0x00000000053e6000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6492, stack(0x00000000061c0000,0x00000000062c0000)]
      0x00000000053d1800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5236, stack(0x00000000060c0000,0x00000000061c0000)]
      0x00000000053d0800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2428, stack(0x00000000052e0000,0x0000000005310000)]
      0x00000000053cf800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10964, stack(0x00000000052b0000,0x00000000052e0000)]
      0x000000000537e000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11248, stack(0x00000000003c0000,0x00000000003f0000)]
      0x0000000005378000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6624, stack(0x0000000000390000,0x00000000003c0000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x000000000536c800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000005dc0000,0x0000000005ec0000] [id=10816]
      0x0000000005407800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000062c0000,0x00000000063c0000] [id=7144]

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    Heap
     PSYoungGen      total 611648K, used 373857K [0x00000007d5560000, 0x0000000800000000, 0x0000000800000000)
      eden space 524288K, 60% used [0x00000007d5560000,0x00000007e8ad3898,0x00000007f5560000)
      from space 87360K, 65% used [0x00000007faab0000,0x00000007fe254c60,0x0000000800000000)
      to   space 87360K, 0% used [0x00000007f5560000,0x00000007f5560000,0x00000007faab0000)
     PSOldGen        total 1398144K, used 2010K [0x0000000780000000, 0x00000007d5560000, 0x00000007d5560000)
      object space 1398144K, 0% used [0x0000000780000000,0x00000007801f6a98,0x00000007d5560000)
     PSPermGen       total 262144K, used 77670K [0x0000000770000000, 0x0000000780000000, 0x0000000780000000)
      object space 262144K, 29% used [0x0000000770000000,0x0000000774bd9a18,0x0000000780000000)

    Code Cache  [0x0000000001120000, 0x00000000016b0000, 0x0000000004120000)
     total_blobs=1661 nmethods=1065 adapters=547 free_code_cache=44626816 largest_free_block=15424

    Dynamic libraries:
    0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000042f000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe
    0x0000000077be0000 - 0x0000000077d89000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
    0x0000000077500000 - 0x000000007761f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
    0x000007fefe130000 - 0x000007fefe19b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
    0x000007fefe540000 - 0x000007fefe61b000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
    0x000007feffbf0000 - 0x000007feffc8f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
    0x000007fefe520000 - 0x000007fefe53f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
    0x000007fefe680000 - 0x000007fefe7ad000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
    0x000000006d8e0000 - 0x000000006e09c000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
    0x0000000077ae0000 - 0x0000000077bda000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
    0x000007fefe860000 - 0x000007fefe8c7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
    0x000007fefe9d0000 - 0x000007fefe9de000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
    0x000007fefe9e0000 - 0x000007fefeaa9000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
    0x000007fef6320000 - 0x000007fef635b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
    0x000007feff8c0000 - 0x000007feff8ee000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
    0x000007fefe410000 - 0x000007fefe519000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
    0x000000006d850000 - 0x000000006d85e000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\verify.dll
    0x000000006d460000 - 0x000000006d487000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\java.dll
    0x000000006d8a0000 - 0x000000006d8b2000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\zip.dll
    0x000007fefeb30000 - 0x000007feff8b8000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.DLL
    0x000007fefeab0000 - 0x000007fefeb21000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
    0x000007feff9e0000 - 0x000007feffbe3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
    0x000007fefdf30000 - 0x000007fefdf3f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
    0x000007fefca90000 - 0x000007fefcc84000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\comctl32.dll
    0x000007fefe8f0000 - 0x000007fefe9c7000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
    0x000007feffd10000 - 0x000007feffee7000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
    0x000007fefe0f0000 - 0x000007fefe126000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
    0x000007fefe1a0000 - 0x000007fefe1ba000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
    0x000007feff940000 - 0x000007feff9d9000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
    0x000007fefc020000 - 0x000007fefc14c000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
    0x000007fef8f00000 - 0x000007fef8f1a000     D:\tcServer\2.0.2\preview\tomcat-6.0.26.B-SR01\bin\winx86_64\wrapper.dll
    0x000000006d6c0000 - 0x000000006d6d7000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\net.dll
    0x000007feff8f0000 - 0x000007feff93d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
    0x000007fefe850000 - 0x000007fefe858000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
    0x000007fefd870000 - 0x000007fefd8c5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
    0x000007fefd860000 - 0x000007fefd867000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
    0x000007fefd250000 - 0x000007fefd257000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
    0x000000006d600000 - 0x000000006d60a000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\management.dll
    0x000007fefcca0000 - 0x000007fefccb5000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
    0x000007fefa900000 - 0x000007fefa915000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
    0x000007fefd6f0000 - 0x000007fefd74b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
    0x000007fefa8f0000 - 0x000007fefa8fb000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
    0x000007fefb8e0000 - 0x000007fefb907000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
    0x000007fefb8c0000 - 0x000007fefb8cb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
    0x000007fefa850000 - 0x000007fefa858000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
    0x000007fefb740000 - 0x000007fefb793000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
    0x000007fefd8d0000 - 0x000007fefd8e7000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
    0x000007fefd5d0000 - 0x000007fefd617000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
    0x000007fefd370000 - 0x000007fefd38e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
    0x000007fefe040000 - 0x000007fefe04f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
    0x000000006d760000 - 0x000000006d766000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\rmi.dll
    0x000000006d820000 - 0x000000006d82b000     D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
    0x000007fefe2a0000 - 0x000007fefe40a000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
    0x000007fefe0e0000 - 0x000007fefe0ef000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
    0x0000000074bd0000 - 0x0000000074be7000     C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64\sqljdbc_auth.dll
    0x000007fefdc10000 - 0x000007fefdc1b000     C:\Windows\system32\secur32.dll
    0x000007fefde90000 - 0x000007fefdeb5000     C:\Windows\system32\SSPICLI.DLL
    0x000007fefd4c0000 - 0x000007fefd4ca000     C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll
    0x000007fefd8f0000 - 0x000007fefd9a4000     C:\Windows\system32\kerberos.DLL
    0x000007fefdb80000 - 0x000007fefdb94000     C:\Windows\system32\cryptdll.dll
    0x000007fefd800000 - 0x000007fefd851000     C:\Windows\system32\msv1_0.DLL
    0x000007fefae10000 - 0x000007fefae37000     C:\Windows\system32\ntdsapi.dll
    0x0000000077db0000 - 0x0000000077db7000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL

    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\tcServer\2.0.2\preview\\tomcat-6.0.26.B-SR01\common\endorsed -Dcatalina.base=D:\tcServer\2.0.2\preview\Patient1 -Dcatalina.home=D:\tcServer\2.0.2\preview\\tomcat-6.0.26.B-SR01 -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\tcServer\2.0.2\preview\Patient1\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.logging.TcServerLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\tcServer\2.0.2\preview\Patient1\conf\logging.properties -Dwrapper.dump.port=-1 -Xss192k -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dgrails.env=preview -Djava.library.path=D:\tcServer\2.0.2\preview\\tomcat-6.0.26.B-SR01\bin\winx86_64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64 -Dwrapper.key=CBRUo14WlAHwrv6B -Dwrapper.port=32003 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=6448 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=5 
    java_command: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp net.covalent.tomcat.wrapper.ThreadDumpWrapper start
    Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

    Environment Variables:
    JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
    PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\shared\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\idrac;D:\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin
    USERNAME=SYSTEM
    ARCH=winx86_64
    OS=Windows_NT
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel



    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

    CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 44 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

    Memory: 4k page, physical 16763992k(4410876k free), swap 33526124k(16701584k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_45-b06), built on Apr  1 2013 12:31:37 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0 (VS2005)

    time: Mon Jun 24 16:57:32 2013
    elapsed time: 22 seconds
```

We have tried JDK versions 1.6.0_20 and 1.6.0_45, rebuilt/redeployed through Jenkins, uninstalled and reinstalled the app through tcServer.

Thanks in advance for any ideas, feel free to request information I may have missed.

Comment: Was temporarily resolved by reverting JDBC driver from 4.0 to 3.0. More to come as we sift through the information.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your crash is caused by some issue with the SQL Server driver when trying to use Integrated Authentication (also referred as Integrated Security)

from MS website (emphasis mine)

The JDBC driver supports the use of Type 2 integrated authentication on Windows operating systems through the integratedSecurity connection string property. **To use integrated authentication, copy the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to a directory on the Windows system path on the computer where the JDBC driver is installed.**

The sqljdbc_auth.dll files are installed in the following location:
\sqljdbc_\\auth\

**Note**
If you are running a 32-bit Java Virtual Machine (JVM), use the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the x86 folder, even if the operating system is the x64 version. **If you are running a 64-bit JVM on a x64 processor, use the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the x64 folder. If you are running a 64-bit JVM on a IA-64 processor, use the sqljdbc_auth.dll file in the IA64 folder**.

Alternatively you can set the java.libary.path system property to specify the directory of the sqljdbc_auth.dll.

For example, if the JDBC driver is installed in the default directory, you can specify the location of the DLL by using the following virtual machine (VM) argument when the Java application is started:
-Djava.library.path=C:\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver\sqljdbc_\enu\auth\x86

{end of quote from MS website}

*PS: To turn off integrated authentication / security change the **integratedSecurity**  flag on the JDBC Connection String to false (ie: integratedSecurity=false)*

More info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check the sql driver (**sqljdbc4.jar**) is up to date and (in sync) i.e from the same release as your  **sqljdbc_auth.dll**.

For example: if your using the auth dll sourced from a download such as this:

`C:\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64\sqljdbc_auth.dll`

Then you should be using the matching driver from the same release:

`C:\Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar`

I suspect your fix worked because you started with a jdbc 3 auth dll mixed with a jdbc 4 driver. Reverting the driver to 3.0 fixed the issue. Try promoting both to 4.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly code does the following:

```
6da0307b:   48 8b 17                mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rdi]
6da0307e:   74 16                   je     0x6da03096
6da03080:   8b 52 08                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rdx+8]
6da03083:   0f b6 0d b6 61 5e 00    movzx  ecx,BYTE PTR ds:0x5e61b6
6da0308a:   48 d3 e2                shl    rdx,cl
6da0308d:   48 03 15 a4 61 5e 00    add    rdx,QWORD PTR ds:0x5e61a4
6da03094:   eb 04                   jmp    0x6da0309a
6da03096:   48 8b 52 08             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rdx+8]
6da0309a:   48 8b 52 70             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rdx+112]
6da0309e:   48 8b ce                mov    rcx,rsi
6da030a1:   e8 4a 98 0c 00          call   0x6dacc8f0
6da030a6:   48 83 7c 24 28 00       cmp    QWORD PTR [rsp+40],0x0
6da030ac:   48 8b f0                mov    rsi,rax
6da030af:   74 0a                   je     0x6da030bb
6da030b1:   48 8d 4c 24 20          lea    rcx,[rsp+32]
6da030b6:   e8 55 72 12 ??          call   0x????
```

at 0x6da0309a it fails cause it can't read memory. The address in rdx (0x000000036d7c8e70) is referencing incorrect memory address according to the memory map.
From the dissassembly, the code does not seem to do the right thing. I suggest you do the following:

1. Run a memory test (memtest86 or similar)
2. Try to increase stack size (192k is too low for a 64bit platform), try -Xss512k
3. Try not to use compressed oops (-XX:-UseCompressedOops)
4. Try verifying that the code above actually matches jvm.dll+0x12309a
5. Try running it on Intel instead of AMD